# Geometry nodes: Taking attributes from parent object

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to take a value from a parent object for use in an embedded geometry node?

For example I have a geometry node which generates a city block which has an group input parameter that sets how many buildings I want in a row.

If I embed this geonode inside a plane, for instance, is there a way I can set it up so that the width of the plane can be used to determine how many buildings I have in a row rather than having to manually input the value?

I would calculate the number of buildings by dividing the width of the plane by the width of a building. But I don't know how to do this in terms of Geometry Nodes.
How do I extract the width of the plane and the width of the building (which is in a collection of similar buildings) in order to divide them?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but I cannot see the problem. The plane knows its width. If you also have the width of one building then plane width / width of building = number of buildings, right?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to do this in terms of geometry nodes. How do I extract the width of the plane and the width of the building (which is in a collection of similar buildings) in order to divide them?

Comment: Oh, I see. You can get the dimensions of the plane with the Bounding Box node. Then use a Vector Math node (Subtract) to calculate Max-Min = dimensions. But I don't know how to get the dimensions of the instances in a collection.

Comment: Here is something similar but the example doesn't use collection. It uses the Accumulate Field node to stack scaled objects: https://youtu.be/kiSi0HC7-aM?feature=shared (5 parts)